# SQL Server : duplicate rows when joining tables and inserting new data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, duplicates, left-join

I have two tables, one that records holidays requested per `EmployeeID` (`tbl.HolidayRequest`):

```
EmployeeID  | HoursRequested |  
------------+----------------+
1           | 8              |     
2           | 16             |     
3           | 8              | 
2           | 8              |
1           | 16             |
```

The second table records the total hours requested per employee (`tbl.HoursRequestedPerEmployee`) which is created by the following query :

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[HoursTakenPerEmployee]
    SELECT
        [dbo].[LotusEmployees].[EmployeeNo.], 
        SUM(ISNULL([dbo].[HolidayRequestForm].[HoursRequested], 0)) AS HoursTaken
    FROM
        [dbo].[LotusEmployees]
    LEFT JOIN
        [dbo].[HolidayRequestForm] ON [dbo].[LotusEmployees].[EmployeeNo.] = [dbo].[HolidayRequestForm].EmployeeNo.]
    GROUP BY
        [dbo].[LotusEmployees].[EmployeeNo.]
```

Result:

```
EmployeeID  | Total HoursRequested |  
------------+----------------------+
1           |       24             |     
2           |       24             |     
3           |        8             |      
1           |       24             |      
2           |       24             |
3           |        8             |
```

How do I update the table `tbl.HoursRequestedPerEmployee` when a new entry is inserted into `tbl.HolidayRequest` and not have duplicates?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Use triggers to handle those changes.

Comment: I am using SSMS

Comment: You should instead create a complex view for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use a view:

```
CREATE VIEW vw_HoursTakenPerEmployee AS
    SELECT le.[EmployeeNo.], 
           COALESCE(SUM(hrf.[HoursRequested]), 0) AS HoursTaken
    FROM [dbo].[LotusEmployees] le LEFT JOIN
         [dbo].[HolidayRequestForm] hrf
          ON le.[EmployeeNo.] = hrf.EmployeeNo.]
    GROUP BYle.[EmployeeNo.];
```

The view will recalculate the information when you need it.

If you feel that you need to store the information in a table (say for performance reasons) then either keep the table up-to-date using triggers (which is yucky!).  Or truncate and recreate the table:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[HoursTakenPerEmployee];

INSERT INTO [dbo].[HoursTakenPerEmployee] . . .
```